# Overloading operator+ in class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Let's say I have a class Number

```
class Number
{
public:
    int numb;

    Number (int g)
    {
        numb = g;
    }

    int operator+(int h)
    {
        return this->numb+h;
    }
};
```

And when I try to use my overloaded operator

```
cout << 3 + s; // doesn't work
cout << s + 3;
```

I understand why it doesn't work, but I don't know how to make it work for `3 + s`

Of course, I can write operator+ with 2 arguments outside the class, but I want to have my operator overloaded in the class.

I've googled it, but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to go: write another overload outside of your class

```
class Number
{
public:
    int numb;

    Number (int g)
    {
        numb = g;
    }

    int operator+(int h)
    {
        return this->numb+h;
    }
};

int operator+(int h, Number& n)
{
    return n.numb+h;
}

int main()
{
    int s = 42;
    std::cout << 3 + s;
    std::cout << s + 3;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0f0b1ac6e516a0d)</kbd>

This also works if your data is private (but make sure the outside function has access to those members)

```
class Number
{
    int numb;

public:
    Number (int g)
    {
        numb = g;
    }

    int operator+(int h)
    {
        return this->numb+h;
    }

    friend int operator+(int, Number&);
};

int operator+(int h, Number& n)
{
    return n.numb+h;
}
```

Comment: Your friends are not always exposed in public, and doing friendships may not be the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

> Of course, I can write operator+ with 2 arguments outside the class, but I want to have my operator overloaded in the class.

This is like saying "Of course I could hammer in my nail with a hammer, but I want to use a screwdriver..."

Some other solutions suggested using both a member and a non-member, but that is redundant: if you add the non-member then you no longer need the member!

The [proper way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) to overload `operator+` is to use the non-member:

```
Number operator+(Number a, Number b)
{
    return a.numb + b.numb;
}
```

Another way to write this is to use `operator+=` as a helper (then your class will support `+=` too):

```
Number operator+(Number a, Number b)
{
    return a += b;
}
```

with member function:

```
Number &operator+=(Number b)
{
    numb += b.numb;
    return *this;
}
```

You could either make `operator+` return `Number` or `int`, your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Just write an operator outside the class that calls the one in your class!

```
template<typename T> T operator+(T a, Number& n)
{
  return n+a;
}
```